# SQL query for pagination with multiple columns; understand OR operator

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sorting

I'm using a tool that generates the Postgresql query below:

```sql
SELECT
    "id",
    "score"
FROM
    "players"
WHERE
    "score" > '11266' OR ( "score" = '11266' AND "id" > '4482' )
ORDER BY
    "score" ASC,
    "id" ASC
    LIMIT 3
```

I need to understand why the `OR` operator?

My **players** table can have many rows with the same `score` but not the same `id`.

Is that `OR` needed when multiple rows has the same `score` value?

Comment: Thumbs up for that tool, doing pagination the correct way!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The purpose of the `OR` -- as you suspect -- is to handle the case where there are ties in the scores.  The idea is to make a stable sort by including the `id`, so this this getting everything *after* `(score, id)`.

Presumably, the values used for `score` and `id` are the last values seen (probably on the previous page, but that is speculation).

A "stable" sort is one that returns the rows in the same order each time it is applied.  Because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, ties imply an *unstable* sort.  Including the `id` makes it stable (assuming that `id` is unique.

Postgres actually supports a simper syntax:

```
where (score, id) > (11266, 4482)
```

Note that I also removed the single quotes.  The values look like numbers so they should be treated as numbers not strings.

Comment: Sorry for bother you.What if `where` clause is this instead: `WHERE
    "score" < '11266' OR ( "score" = '11266' AND "id" > '4482' )`. Is there a simpler syntax?

Comment: @FredHors . . . The tuple syntax seems simpler to me.