# Postgres simpler syntax for multiple columns stable sorting

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance, sorting

I know (from this: [SQL query for pagination with multiple columns; understand OR operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60433647/sql-query-for-pagination-with-multiple-columns-understand-or-operator)) that the `WHERE` clause in the below Postgres syntax

```sql
SELECT
    "id",
    "score"
FROM
    "players"
WHERE
    "score" > '11266' OR ( "score" = '11266' AND "id" > '4482' )
ORDER BY
    "score" ASC,
    "id" ASC
    LIMIT 3
```

is the long form of:

```sql
where (score, id) > (11266, 4482)
```

But what if I have the query below?

```sql
SELECT
    "id",
    "score"
FROM
    "players"
WHERE
    (
        ( ( "created_at" ) < '2020-02-27 08:57:36.774147+00' ) -- note the "<"
        OR ( ( ( "created_at" ) = '2020-02-27 08:57:36.774147+00' ) AND ( ( "score" ) > 11266 ) ) 
        OR ( ( ( "created_at" ) = '2020-02-27 08:57:36.774147+00' ) AND ( ( "score" ) = 11266 ) AND ( ( "id" ) > 4482 ) ) 
    )
ORDER BY
    "created_at" DESC,
    "score",
    "id"
    LIMIT 3
```

Can you tell me how I can deal with this kind of query in general?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply negate the values in your `score` and `id` comparisons so that you can use `<` for them instead of `>`; and then you can use a tuple compare:

```
SELECT
    "id",
    "score"
FROM
    players
WHERE
    ("created_at", -"score", -"id") < ('2020-02-27 08:57:36.774147+00', -11266, -4482) 
ORDER BY
    "created_at" DESC,
    "score",
    "id"
    LIMIT 3
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/87d5b/5)

Comment: Oh! This is amazing!!!! It will save me a lot of code (I'm translating this in code)! Thanks.

Comment: Postgres is amazing!

Comment: @FredHors tuple (row) comparisons are actually standard SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, tuple comparisons require that all keys be in the same direction.

Your `order by` is not consistent with the `where`.  It should be:

```
ORDER BY "created_at" desc,
         "score",
         "id"
```

You could introduce new columns (basically some sort of negation of existing columns) so the ordering is the same for all keys.